# Seleccionar label através .find

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou a tentar criar/adaptar uma `tree list`, no entanto não estou a conseguir expandir a minha lista ao clicar sobre uma label.

Lista:

```
<div id="listContainer">
  <ul id="expList">         
    <li style="">
        <label style="margin-top: 50px;border-style: solid;  border-width: 1px; border-color: #7C7C7C; background-color:#E0E0E0">
        Item A
        </label>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    itens lista A
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

A partida o erro parte da minha função js para expandir a lista:

```
function prepareList() {
        $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)')
        .click(function (event) {
            if (this == event.target) {
                $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
                $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
            }
            return false;
        })
        .addClass('collapsed')
        .children('ul').hide();

...
...
}
```

Já tentei fazer find da label na `expList` só para **testar** e não consegui resolver a questão:

```
$('#expList').find('label')
        .click(function (event) {
...
...
}
```

Segue o código completo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jrqxdzc/)

PS.- Se clicarem fora da lista, a mesma expande

Comment: Qual é a ideia desta linha? `if (this == event.target) {` o que pretendes com ela? (só para perceber melhor o que procuras)

Comment: @Sergio, o problema é dessa linha (se a tirar funciona como quero). Vou apagar a pergunta, pois a partida não ajudará ninguém no futuro. Obrigado pela ajuda ;)

Comment: Não apagues. O problema nessa linha é que o `this` e o `event.target` nem sempre são o mesmo elemento. E isso gera confusão a muita gente, daí a pergunta é util...

Comment: Ah já estou a entender o meu erro. A partida o meu `event.target` tinha o valor algo como "cliquei na li", e o meu `this` faz referência ao elemento. É isso que estás a tentar dizer?

Comment: Em que cenário queres que esse `if` dê false? ou seja, como está, o this é o `<li>` e o `event.target` é o elemento descendente do `this` que foi clicado, por exemplo o `<label>`. A não ser que o `<li>` tenha por exemplo um padding vai ser dificil de ter esse if a dar true.

Comment: A partida ao clicar fora da `li` ia dar falso. Mas como a `label` está dentro da `li` não entendi o erro

Comment: Para evitar que o click nos filhos dispare o evento click dos pais, use event.stopPropagation();

Comment: Nesse caso essa linha não é necessária pois o `$('#expList').find('li:has(ul)')` só seleciona `li`'s. E já agora podes usar `$('#expList li:has(ul)')` somente.

Comment: Exacto, já percebi porque não deu. Pensava que também ia selecionar os filhos da `li`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe uma diferença entre usar o `this` e o `event.target` dentro de um oscultador de evento.

Se o oscultador esiver amarrado a um elemento sem descendentes, então `this == event.target`. Mas no caso de o evento estar associado/amarrado a um parente então o `event.target` será o elemento descendente do inicial, aquele que recebeu o click. O evento vai depois subir no DOM (bubbling) até chegar ao event handler que é então ativado tendo como `this` o elemento que está no seletor.

No seu caso o `this` vai sempre ser um `li`, como pedido pelo seletor `li:has(ul)`, e o event.target o `<label>`. 
Pode haver casos em que o `event.target == li`. No caso de ter um padding grande e o utilizador clicar fora dos limites do `label` e ainda dentro do `li`. Mas em qualquer dos casos o `this` será-lhe atribuído o `li` em questão.

Olhando para [este exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/7jrqxdzc/2/) com cor de fundo no `li` dá para perceber quando o `this == li`